# Solving least squares with QR

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, least-squares

In order to avoid $A^TA$'s bad condition we decompose $A$ into $A = QR$ , $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n*m} $ , $R \in \mathbb{R}^{m*m} $ , $Q^TQ = I$ . But in my textbook it says that $$
min||r||_2^2 = min||b - Ax||_2^2 = min||Q^Tb - Rx||_2^2
$$

And proceeds to say that the best solution is the $x$ so that
$$
Q^Tb - Rx = 0 
$$
$$
\iff x = R^{-1}Q^Tb
$$

Doesn't that mean though that 
$$
x = R^{-1}Q^Tb
\iff QRx = b \iff Ax = b
$$

So what happened here? Is R reversible only when the system is not overdetermined? I'm a little bit confused. Thank you!